# Is there any UIViewController as same as MobileApp's "Info" view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any predefined UIViewController/NavigationController in the IPhone API as same as "Info" in "Phone/Mobile" application?

For example, suppose I received a call or dialed a number, which is not stored in address book. Then later I wanna see the details of that number, IPhone navigates me to the "Info" view when I click the "Detail disclosure button" in the calls table view. Exactly I want the same "Info" ViewController. Before going to design my customized UIViewController I just wanna know, is there any predefined ViewController in the API?

P:S: I searched the address book API, but unfortunately I didn't notice any such contoller.

Regards,
Prathap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really. Use a `UITableViewController` in the "grouped" style (`UITableViewStyleGrouped`) and initialize your cells with the `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` style, adding a custom `tableHeaderView` if necessary to contain any title / non-listworthy information.

Answer (score 2):

no, you don't have something this specific in the API.

if you want that kind of viewcontroller, you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a UITableViewController with a complex header view and a different text color for the cell's textLabel.

Comment: Thanx refulgentis,

Is it an UITableViewController or UIViewController? I got confused. By seeing that view I just think that is an UIViewController. 

If it is an UITableViewController, how can I customize it as same as "Info" view? Is there any online tutorial available for it?

Comment: UITableViewController (the entire view scrolls up and down, not just the grouped table at the bottom).  As he said, there is a custom UIView for the table's tableHeaderView.  And no, there is no exact tutorial for doing this specific view, but it's not that complex to construct.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the API, I found that "ABUnknownPersonViewController" is suitable to serve the purpose. And also "ABPersonViewController" can be used to display the if you get a contact details (if that contact exists in the Address Book).

Thanks refulgentis and Brad Larson for your comments.

refulgentis, as I said above, "Info" is an "UIViewController" not "UITableViewController".

Regards,
Prathap.